# Does SSRS2008 R2 support SSRS2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, ssrs-2008-r2

I've recently installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and would like to know whether SSRS/Business Intelligence will fully support the Projects and Reports previously created and maintained within SSRS 2008?

I've gone ahead and created a copy of one of my main projects and converted it. So it can now be used within SSRS2008R2. So far, everything looks fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work find but it you do have some problems like I has with some reports not all of them I did something like this .....
1) In your `RDL file` once you have opened it in `any text Editor` just look for the following

```
    <Report xmlns:rd=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner”
xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition“>
```

And replace it with:

```
    <Report xmlns:rd=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner”
xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2009/01/reportdefinition“>
```

**Warning**
I only did it with the reports which were causing problems. but when I did it to the reports which werent causing any error "was trying to be on safe side" they started coming up with other issues. I recommend to do this find and replace only with the reports which arent working as expected.